# Database connection with c# using access

Tags: c#, ms-access, ms-access-2016

I want to connect to my MS Access database from c# and I am getting the following error:

> unrecognized database format 'data.accdb'

What should I do? Please help

Comment: show us some code: how are you connection, what is your connection string...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use connection string like this:

```
public static string ConStr = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.Oledb.15.0; Data Source=D:\db.accdb;";


public static void DeleteTable(string TableName)
{
    OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(OLEDB.ConStr);
    OleDbCommand oleDbCommand = new OleDbCommand(string.Format("delete from [{0}]", (object) TableName), connection);
    try
    {
       connection.Open();
       oleDbCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch
    {
    }
    finally
    {
        connection.Close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I made a class for that. It works perfectly with the latest visual studio, or vs 2010 with access 2010. If you have a newer version of access you need to install the [Access Database Engine](https://www.microsoft.com/it-it/download/details.aspx?id=13255). It also contains a function that strips the apostrofe preventing your sql being hacked using sql injection and a method for creating md5 hashes.

```
using System.Data;
using System.Data.OleDb;
using System.Text;
using System.Security.Cryptography;

public class Database
{

    #region Variables

    String Name;
    String Path;
    String ConnectionString;
    OleDbConnection Connection;

    #endregion

    #region Init Destroy

    public Database(String Name)
    {
        this.Name = @"App_Data\" + Name;
        Path = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath(this.Name);
        ConnectionString = @"Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; " +
                            "Data Source = " + Path + ";" +
                            "Persist Security Info = False;";
        Connection = new OleDbConnection(ConnectionString);
        if (Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            Connection.Open();
        }
    }

    public void finalize()
    {
        if (Connection.State == System.Data.ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            try { Connection.Close(); }
            catch { }
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Queries

    public void execute(String query)
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, Connection);
        command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }

    public OleDbDataReader select(String query)
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, Connection);
        OleDbDataReader data = command.ExecuteReader();
        return data;
    }

    public DataSet selectData(String query)
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, Connection);
        OleDbDataAdapter adp = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        adp.Fill(ds);
        return ds;
    }

    public object scalar(String query)
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, Connection);
        object data = new object();
        data = command.ExecuteScalar();
        return data;
    }

    #endregion

    #region Encryption Security

    public String stripInjection(String field)
    {
        String x = field.Replace(@"'", string.Empty);
        x = x.Replace(@"""", string.Empty);
        return x;
    }

    public string md5Hash(string input)
    {
        StringBuilder hash = new StringBuilder();
        MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5provider = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
        byte[] bytes = md5provider.ComputeHash(new UTF8Encoding().GetBytes(input));

        for (int i = 0; i < bytes.Length; i++)
        {
            hash.Append(bytes[i].ToString("x2"));
        }
        return hash.ToString().ToUpper();
    }

    #endregion

}
```

Don't put finalize instructions in the destructor of the class (As Microsoft says in the documentation because it will launch some exceptions). Just call it when you have finished your tasks:

```
Database database = new Database("data.accdb");
DataSet result = database.selectData("SELECT something FROM table WHERE condition;");
database.finalize();
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy Your Databse file .accdb in Debug folder of project then add app.config file in your project

Write below code in app.config  in Configuration tag

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="db" connectionString="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=|DataDirectory|\sse_db.accdb;Persist Security Info=False;"
      providerName="System.Data.Oledb" />
</connectionStrings>
```

1)Add System.Configuration Reference 
Use connection object as follows

```
OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db"].ConnectionString);
```